# Maximum update depth exceeded при диспаче в функциональном компоненте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Начал прикручивать **redux** к **react** и столкнулся с

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Работаю под CRA.

мой App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

function App(props) {
  props.onAddLoader({
      name: 'image',
      loaded: false
  }); //Падает в цикл, как при componentDidMount

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    loaded: state
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    onAddLoader: ({name, loaded}) => {
      dispatch({type: 'ADD_LOADER', nameD: name, loadedD: loaded});
    }
  })
)(App);
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем дело? Не могу ничего найти на этот счет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все достаточно просто. смотри  ты при рендере функции вызываешь `onAddLoader`, что вызывает изменения стора что в свою очередь вызывает новый рендер. и так до бесконечности. и непонятно что ты делаешь  с  loaded. он у тебя нигде не используется? 
как пример:

```
 class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
       const {onAddLoader} = this.props
       onAddLoader({
         name: 'image',
         loaded: false
  })
  }

    render(){
      return (
        <React.Fragment>

         </React.Fragment>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: Loaded будет использоваться, как только заработает диспач. Что нужно сделать, чтобы он адекватно вызывался?

Comment: И я хотел вызвать диспач до рендера (до ретурна). Как это сделать?

Comment: @RyanWright , а когда нужно что бы   вызываклся action?

Comment: @ как вариант переписать  все в  класс и на componentDidMount  подписать,  или возится с useEffect

Comment: В теле будет функция фетчер

Comment: С useEffect получилось так же, но скрипт не остановился. Цикл шел вечно

Comment: ну я   сторонник классов, с эффектами нужно делать или флаги  или  слушать изменения  пропса определенного

Comment: @RyanWright,  опиши может более детально  задачу.  помощь будет более квалифицированной)))